# Spring Data JDBC nesting Entities of the same Type

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I want to map a Navigation with Spring Data JDBC.
There is an Aggregate Root which holds an object of type "Directory".
The Directory should for instance a path and a an ordered Set of child Directories.
How could I achieve this with Spring Data JDBC?

```java
public class Hierarchy {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Directory root;
}
```

```java
public class Directory {

    private String path;

    private Set<Directory> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Directory(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JDBC doesn't directly support recursive structures like this, but that doesn't mean you can't use it to store them.

What I would do is:

1. store all directories in a `List` in `Hierarchy`
2. keep a reference to the parent `Directory` as a simple `int` referencing the list index holding the parent `Directory`.
3. create whatever ever structure you need for the rest of your code during/after construction of the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jens,
do you mean like this?

```
public class Hierarchy {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Directory> directories;

    public Hierarchy() {
        this.name = "";
        this.directories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Hierarchy(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.directories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Hierarchy(String name, List<Directory> directories) {
        this.name = name;
        this.directories.addAll(directories);
    }

    ...
}
```

```
public class Directory {
    private String path;
    private Integer parentIndex;

    public Directory() {
    }

    public Directory(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.parentIndex = null;
    }

    public Directory(String path, Integer parentIndex) {
        this.path = path;
        this.parentIndex = parentIndex;
    }

    ...
}
```

with a schema like this:

```
-- Hierarchy Aggregate
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hierarchy
(
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS directory
(
    hierarchy     INT,
    hierarchy_key INT,
    path          TEXT,
    parent_index  INT
);
```

And assemble it here:

```
@Component
public class HierarchyLoadListener extends AbstractRelationalEventListener<Hierarchy> {
    private static final Logger Log = getLogger(HierarchyLoadListener.class);
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<Hierarchy> event) {
        Log.info("### onBeforeConvert ###");
        Log.info(event.getEntity().toString());
    }
}
```